# WIX 3.8 minimized installer progress bar window

Tags: wix, progress-bar, silent-installer

IM am using WIX3.8 and I want a Silent Installation, but still appears the progress bar Window. Is there a way to Hide it or minimized it during installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WiX produces MSI's.  The MSI does not get to choose how it is run.  Use the `/qn` flag when calling `MSIEXEC` to hide the UI.

`MSIEXEC` help:

```
Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.9600.16384 

msiexec /Option  [Optional Parameter]

Install Options
     
        Installs or configures a product
    /a 
        Administrative install - Installs a product on the network
    /j  [/t ] [/g ]
        Advertises a product - m to all users, u to current user
     
        Uninstalls the product
Display Options
    /quiet
        Quiet mode, no user interaction
    /passive
        Unattended mode - progress bar only
    /q[n|b|r|f]
        Sets user interface level
        n - No UI
        b - Basic UI
        r - Reduced UI
        f - Full UI (default)
    /help
        Help information
Restart Options
    /norestart
        Do not restart after the installation is complete
    /promptrestart
        Prompts the user for restart if necessary
    /forcerestart
        Always restart the computer after installation
Logging Options
    /l[i|w|e|a|r|u|c|m|o|p|v|x|+|!|*] 
        i - Status messages
        w - Nonfatal warnings
        e - All error messages
        a - Start up of actions
        r - Action-specific records
        u - User requests
        c - Initial UI parameters
        m - Out-of-memory or fatal exit information
        o - Out-of-disk-space messages
        p - Terminal properties
        v - Verbose output
        x - Extra debugging information
        + - Append to existing log file
        ! - Flush each line to the log
        * - Log all information, except for v and x options
    /log 
        Equivalent of /l* 
Update Options
    /update [;Update2.msp]
        Applies update(s)
    /uninstall [;Update2.msp] /package 
        Remove update(s) for a product
Repair Options
    /f[p|e|c|m|s|o|d|a|u|v] 
        Repairs a product
        p - only if file is missing
        o - if file is missing or an older version is installed (default)
        e - if file is missing or an equal or older version is installed
        d - if file is missing or a different version is installed
        c - if file is missing or checksum does not match the calculated value
        a - forces all files to be reinstalled
        u - all required user-specific registry entries (default)
        m - all required computer-specific registry entries (default)
        s - all existing shortcuts (default)
        v - runs from source and recaches local package
Setting Public Properties
    [PROPERTY=PropertyValue]

Consult the Windows ® Installer SDK for additional documentation on the
command line syntax.

Copyright © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Portions of this software are based in part on the work of the Independent JPEG Group.
```

Comment: Thanks, i Have tried with '/qn' but nothing happen... It did not install at all. Got an error "Installation success or error status: 1603" And I do not what it means.. I though to minimized installer Windows, but I do not find the way yet.

Comment: What is the full command line you used?  `1603` ("A fatal error occurred during installation") is usually a file system permission error (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834484).  You may get more error information by passing `/l*v log.txt` to get verbose logging in `log.txt`.